# I did "rm -rf" on a disk volume with mysql database files, any possible way to reconstruct the files?

Tags: data-recovery

I had a separate disk volume on an aws instance mounted at `/mysql`. I did an `rm -rf on /mysql`. Unfortunately, the mysql dumps were not backing up the database due to some misconfiguration.

I'm hoping that since the files were on a separate volume and nothing has been written to the drive since doing the `rm -rf`, it might be possible to recover the files. The drive is not encrypted.

Comment: Before anything else unmount the drive. Now

Comment: Thanks yeah. I am using ext4magic to try to recover files. Looks like the ibdata1 file was able to be recovered. Trying to restore it now.